# How to make a Eclipse plug-in deployable in many Eclipse versions?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wrote my own Eclipse plug-in for Eclipse Oxygen 3a. It works perfectly in Eclipse Oxygen 3a.

Now I'm being required to deploy the same plug-in in newer versions of Eclipse, but when the plug-in is being installed in, for instance, Eclipse Photon, the install window says:

```
Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while: ...
```

It indeed takes a long while and ends up saying that my plug-in will not be installed.

What to do to make this plug-in workable to more than one Eclipse version?

## Update 1

As asked, this is the Require-Bundle:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.ui.views;bundle-version="3.8.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui;bundle-version="3.13.52",
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.13.50"
```

There is no Import-Bundle.

## Update 2

The feature.xml file can be seen below. I have a plug-in site deployed in an internal Apache web server and use "Install new software" option in Help menu of Eclipse to install from thare.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="MyPluginFeature"
      label="MyPlugin"
      version="0.4.0"
      provider-name="MyPlugin.com"
      plugin="MyPlugin">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
   </license>

   <url>
      <update label="MyPlugin site" url="http://acme.com/myplugin"/>
   </url>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.expressions" version="3.2.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.filesystem" version="1.3.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="3.12.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="3.12.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="3.13.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.filesystem" version="1.7.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.text" version="3.6.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.osgi" version="3.7.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="3.8.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.jobs" version="3.2.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.registry" version="3.4.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences" version="3.4.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.contenttype" version="3.3.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.app" version="1.0.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="3.2.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.registry" version="3.2.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.osgi" version="3.2.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.commands" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="3.2.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.swt" version="3.103.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jface" version="3.13.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.workbench" version="3.105.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.expressions" version="3.4.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.swt" version="3.104.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.commands" version="3.4.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="3.3.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.compare.core" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.expressions" version="3.4.100" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jface.text" version="3.8.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="3.11.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.filesystem" version="1.2.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.text" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring" version="3.7.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jface.text" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.navigator" version="3.3.200" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.compare" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.team.core" version="3.4.100" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.team.ui" version="3.4.100" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.editors"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.views" version="3.8.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.ide"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.ui" version="3.13.52" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.core" version="3.13.50" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.core.resources"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.jdt.core"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.text"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ui"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.jface"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="MetaCoder"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.4.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

## Update 3

Remediation window:
[image]

## Update 4

After the unsuccessful atempt to install the plug-in in Eclipse JEE 2019-Jul I had the following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: MyPlugin 0.4.0 (MyPluginFeature.feature.group 0.4.0)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 4.13.0.v20190916-1323 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.13.0.v20190916-1323)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core File Systems 1.7.500.v20190620-1312 (org.eclipse.core.filesystem 1.7.500.v20190620-1312)
    Core File Systems 1.7.0.v20170406-1337 (org.eclipse.core.filesystem 1.7.0.v20170406-1337)
    Core File Systems 1.7.400.v20190518-1151 (org.eclipse.core.filesystem 1.7.400.v20190518-1151)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: MyPlugin 0.4.0 (MetaCoderFeature.feature.group 0.4.0)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.core.filesystem [1.7.0.v20170406-1337,1.7.0.v20170406-1337]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.13.0.v20190916-1323 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.13.0.v20190916-1323)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.core.filesystem [1.7.500.v20190620-1312,1.7.500.v20190620-1312]
```

## Update 5

IN the feature editor I decided to click the [Compute] button and all the dependencies were recomputed. As a result below we have the new feature.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="MyPluginFeature"
      label="MyPlugin"
      version="0.4.0"
      provider-name="ACME"
      plugin="MyPlugin">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
   </license>

   <url>
      <update label="Site do MyPlugin" url="http://example.org/myplugin"/>
   </url>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui" version="3.5.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="3.12.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jface.text" version="3.8.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="3.12.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.editors"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.views" version="3.8.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui.ide"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.ui" version="3.13.52" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.core" version="3.13.50" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="MyPlugin"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.4.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

Comment: This is often the dependencies of your plug-in. What plug-ins does it depend on and what version ranges of those plug-ins does it specify? Show us the `Require-Bundle` and `Import-Package` parts of the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: After waiting for the alternate solution calculation, there should be an option to show the original error message. That will tell you what exactly is wrong. Usually it's missing plugins or a missing version of a plugin.

Comment: The `Require-Bundle` section looks fine (besides missing version ranges, but this a different thing). Do you have also a feture and an update site? If yes, please show your `feature.xml`. How exactly did you install the plug-in?

Comment: @kapex: the window shows an immense list of plug-in names and versions under a node labeled "Will be upgraded/downgraded". All itens have a green up arrow preceding them. Another node that is labeled "Will not be installed" has one single item listing my plug-in. The option "Show original error and build my own solution" is maked.

Comment: @howlger: just added!

Comment: @AlexSC I think you have to uncheck all checkboxes (the ones that say "install fewer items" and "update items already isntalled"), then it will show some text instead of listing plugins.

Comment: The feature.xml is including a number of Eclipse plug-ins using `<plugin` - I think that may be causing issues - only use that for your own plug-ins, use the `requires` section for Eclipse plug-ins.

Comment: @kapex: your tip was perfect! I just updated the question to include the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **`feature.xml` only your own plug-ins should be specified as `<plugin ... />`**, not the (Eclipse) plug-ins/bundles that are required.

For example,

```
    <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.core.resources"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>
```

makes the plug-in/bundle `org.eclipse.core.resources` of the current version (`version="0.0.0"` is a placeholder that will be replaced by the current version when building the update site) part of the thing that can be installed. Because `org.eclipse.core.resources` is a singleton plug-in/bundle (`Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.resources; singleton:=true`), it cannot be used with the plug-in/bundle of another version. This prevents your plug-in from being deployable in many Eclipse versions.

Comment: Sorry, but the current configuration of features.xml file (see Update 5) goes like your anawer, but the problem continues the same.

Comment: @AlexSC Please double-check and make sure to have incremented the feature version number (or use `version="0.4.0.qualifier"` instead of `version="0.4.0"` to have a version number containing a timestamp). By the way, you can also use directly a directory instead of a web server to host the update site (that might save you a step when testing). Up to _Update 4_ everything makes sense, including what the others say. If you still have problems, please show the updated error message (update your _Update 4_).