# The product definition is not pulling in dependencies from the required features

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am converting a plug-in-based RCP product to a feature-based one. I have grouped the plug-ins into 4 features and have created a traget definition containing all the required plug-ins.

When I view the dependency lists of each new feature, they look about right but when I run the product, I get a long list of `Missing Constraint` errors which seem to refer to plug-ins listed the `Dependencies` of my features.

Do I need to explicitly define these plug-ins as `Included plug-ins` in each feature definition? Why isn't the project definition itself loading the plug-ins automatically?

Comment: Please show an example to reproduce this issue. Required plug-ins must not be defined as included plug-ins (otherwise [you will get this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067265/6505250)).

Answer (score 1):

The 'Run Configuration' for your RCP in the 'Run > Run Configurations...' menu determines what is available when your run your code from within Eclipse.

On the 'Plug-ins' tab you can select 'features selected below' on the 'Launch with' combo to select your features. Use the 'Validate Plug-ins' button to check the selection.

For building (maven + tycho is strongly recommended) the features in the .product file are used.

- On the 'Overview' tab of the .product editor select 'features' for 'the product configuration is based on' combo
- On the 'Content' tab add your features.

Example contents configuration:
[image: Example contents configuration]

Example run configuration:
[image: Run Configuration]

Comment: I can create a Lauch Configuration ok - I can click the button to select all the required plug-ins. It's the product build that is giving me problems. I'm looking for the equivalent action to adding the required plugins...

Comment: I have added more about the .product file configuration. Note that using 'maven + tycho' is now the only recommended way of doing RCP builds.